# BIRT integration into Spring web app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, birt

So I am developing a Spring Web Application using -

1. Eclipse Indigo
2. Spring MVC
3. Spring JDBC
4. JDK 1.5

I've configured my controllers, contexts, etc and everything is running properly. Now, I have a few **excel** files on my server which I want to display as nice BIRT reports(HTML) in my web app(view).

**Question-**
Where do I start ? Which parts of BIRT(3.7.2) do I need to download or integrate into eclipse ? How to write Java code to pick up the excel(xls,xlsx) file from server, convert it into a BIRT report and show it in my JSP ? 
If someone can just point me towards the right direction..

Comment: start here http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Comment: Spring Framework with Birt:  http://www.springsource.org/BusinessIntelligenceWithSpringAndBIRT

Comment: Read/write Excel files in Java:  http://poi.apache.org/